# The app runs correctly in the emulator, but on a real device do not

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When i run it on the emulator the app works fine, every single feature, but when i install it on my device, it doesn't work, i.e. when i open the camera, it just stop the application, or if i open the gallery my app stops, this is strange.

```
forced close
```

I am working in AngularJS, using Ionic and Cordova.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide some code or debug log